# Linked formulas in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to set up a linked worksheet and need to copy the formula with mixed variables.  I would like to set up `='by name'!$A3` and copy so that the next formula is `='by name'!A4`, but when I copy `='by name'!$A3`, Excel keeps both variables constant.  Why?

Comment: Are you trying within the same workbook or different excel files?

Comment: I am in the same workbook but on two different worksheets. The first worksheet is "by name". When I link to it using ='by name'!$A3 i am able to pull up the value in "by name" cell A3. I then try to copy that cell to another cell but my excel (2010) keeps both variables constant even though I feel like my formula should allow the 2nd variable to change. I use that often within one worksheet but it doesn't seem to want to work in linked formulas. Am I going to have to manually enter the linked formula? UGH.

Comment: odd I just was able to copy it (and the variables changed correctly) but only on different rows when I want to copy it to different columns.

Comment: Well I think I managed to figure this out.  It is a two step process.  First you copy to different rows and then use the transpose special paste to get it to columns!

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming. It should be posted on superuser.com, not here.

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct,

You are trying to copy the values of A3 to A10 Cells to another sheet.

**A3 - A10** is assumed example.

### Difference between `=Sheet1!A3` Vs. `=Sheet1!$A3`?

**`=Sheet1!A3`**  -  This is to copy the values of 1st sheet to the 2nd sheet.

**Example:** If you place this formula, when you double-click on plus **"+"** symbol it will fill **A3 - A10** cell with the values from the 1st sheet

**`=Sheet1!$A3`** -  This will be provide reference only to **A3 cell** and copy the values of 1st sheet to the 2nd sheet.

**Example:** If you place this formula, when you double-click on plus **"+"** symbol it will fill **A3 - A10** cell with the **A3** value of 1st sheet to 2nd sheet.

Answer (score 0):

To understand your problem, you have to understand the use of the `$` (dollar sign) in Excel formula.

**The dollar is used to keep reference to a row or a column when you copy-paste a formula.**

---

If you copy-paste a formula from `Sheet2`, cell A1 that refers to `='by name'!A1`, Excel will **automatically adapt the formula** when you copy-paste (or drag-and-drop) the formula.

For instance, when you will copy-paste the formula from `Sheet2`, cell `A1` to Sheet2`, cell`B2`, the new formula will be:`='by name'!B2` because Excel thinks you want to *shift* the reference.

If you want to keep reference to a row or a column, you can add a `$` before the column or the row you want to keep. For instance, if you copy-paste this formula from `A1` to `B2`:

- `='by name'!$A$1` will become `='by name'!$A$1`
- `='by name'!$A1` will become `='by name'!$A2` (keep the column)
- `='by name'!A$1` will become `='by name'!B$1` (keep the row)
- `='by name'!A1` will become `='by name'!A1` (keep both)